# Next api and backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, backend

In NEXT project, API Routes let you create an API endpoint inside a Next.js app. You can do so by creating a function inside the pages/api directory that has the following format:

```
// req = HTTP incoming message, res = HTTP server response
export default function handler(req, res) {
  // ...
}
```

Then what is different between express backend and next api.
If I use next api, can I build all backend and frontend?
And how can I get access to database on next api?
Is that possible?
If I use database configuration on next api, then how will it be rendered in SSG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak of what I know about the question. In my current project, we use an Express server with Next.js.

**Reasons to Use Express With Next**

Express has lots of middlewares available and the ecosystem around it is solid. In my case, we already have multiple Express apps in production. Adding the Express layer helps us keep the behaviors of different servers as similar as possible.

**Reasons to Use Next API Route Directly**

Next API routes are straightforward if you don't have many custom middlewares. Next.js already come with common middlewares to handle many common tasks. I think the decision comes down to where you are going to deploy your application. If you want to use Vercel with serverless functions, you can't use a custom server. You can find more information about [serverless here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/build-target#serverless-target)

**Can You Build Backend & Frontend with Next and its API Routes**

Yes, you can absolutely do it. But you have to decide whether this is a more suitable solution.

**Can You Access Database in API Routes**

Yes

**What About SSG**

As far as I know, API routes are part of a server bundle. Next.js will not statically generate `page/api/**/*`. All your SSG pages should work as expected.

I hope I provided some useful information here.